# Chrome home page is not loading properly

Tags: google-chrome

[image: My home page]
Some things changed after what i don't know. I can't delete thumbnails or add. Search bar is not rounded. The button minimize is changed. Please, help. What should i do? I use Ubuntu 18.10. nvidia-390

Comment: I am having a similar problem since update 73.0.3683.86-1 and the previous version. I am getting only the Google logo and search bar, no icons at all, and it is displayed delayed appox. 2 seconds. The latest Chromium version does not have this bug! Using stable releases, Ubuntu 16.04, Intel graphics

Answer (score -1):

This might be due to an update for Chrome, but I'm not sure about the thumbnails. I would check which version of Chrome you're using and see if it's the latest version available. Look at the change logs for recent Chrome updates and see if the changes are associated with anything you're experiencing.

[Chrome Releases](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/)